# Create new object based on two other objects

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have two objects in my redux store. The first holds expenditures by their ID. The second holds all expenditures ids based on their day as key.

**expenditures by ID**

```
expenditures: {
   byId: {
      '0e1ca91f-aad2-44c7-985a-dfd014bb67fa': {
        id: '0e1ca91f-aad2-44c7-985a-dfd014bb67fa',
        createdAt: 1480510965381,
        description: 'shoes',
        categoryId: 13,
        value: -4,
        day: 1440374400000
      },
      '65711ad0-407d-42ca-aa13-c468a56d6ee6': {
        id: '65711ad0-407d-42ca-aa13-c468a56d6ee6',
        createdAt: 1480510965470,
        description: 'groceries',
        categoryId: 12,
        value: -53.65,
        day: 1440374400000
      },
   },
}
```

**expenditures by days**

```
expenditures: {
   byDays: {
      '1440374400000': [
        '0e1ca91f-aad2-44c7-985a-dfd014bb67fa',
        '65711ad0-407d-42ca-aa13-c468a56d6ee6'
      ],
      '1440720000000': [
        '02180819-3684-480a-96c4-e9fceb2557d0',
        '2201f929-7390-4b24-ba6b-b92e850fb964',
        'f492ad3a-c580-429a-8b68-a2259658d0cd',
        'f654725a-8eee-4e9a-97a8-4fd5a331473e',
        'eedc5a7d-0320-41a1-b190-79f967b42961'
      ],
   }
}
```

In order to render these now in my component I need a new object based on **expenditures by days** that is

1. Filtered by a specific date
2. Ordered descending
3. Contains expenditure objects instead of their id's

Something like this:

```
expenditures: {
    byDay: {
      '1440374400000': [
        {
          id: '0e1ca91f-aad2-44c7-985a-dfd014bb67fa',
          createdAt: 1480510965381,
          description: 'shoes',
          categoryId: 13,
          value: -4,
          day: 1440374400000
        },
        {
          id: '65711ad0-407d-42ca-aa13-c468a56d6ee6',
          createdAt: 1480510965470,
          updatedAt: 1480510965470,
          description: 'groceries',
          categoryId: 12,
          value: -53.65,
          day: 1440374400000
        }
      ],
   }
}
```

What I have so far:

```
Object.keys(state.expenditures.byDays)
      .filter((day) => day >= currentFirstDay && day <= currentLastDay)
      .sort((a, b) => b - a)
```

This gives me a filtered and sorted array based on expenditures.byDays. However, I don't know how to proceed. I tried some stuff for the last hours with `reduce` but I cannot fix it.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A solution I can think of. Refer repl below*

```
const state = {
  expenditures: {
    byId: {
      '0e1ca91f-aad2-44c7-985a-dfd014bb67fa': {
        id: '0e1ca91f-aad2-44c7-985a-dfd014bb67fa',
        createdAt: 1480510965381,
        description: 'shoes',
        categoryId: 13,
        value: -4,
        day: 1440374400000
      },
      '65711ad0-407d-42ca-aa13-c468a56d6ee6': {
        id: '65711ad0-407d-42ca-aa13-c468a56d6ee6',
        createdAt: 1480510965470,
        description: 'groceries',
        categoryId: 12,
        value: -53.65,
        day: 1440374400000
      },
    },
    byDays: {
      '1440374400000': [
        '0e1ca91f-aad2-44c7-985a-dfd014bb67fa',
        '65711ad0-407d-42ca-aa13-c468a56d6ee6'
      ],
      '1440720000000': [
        '02180819-3684-480a-96c4-e9fceb2557d0',
        '2201f929-7390-4b24-ba6b-b92e850fb964',
        'f492ad3a-c580-429a-8b68-a2259658d0cd',
        'f654725a-8eee-4e9a-97a8-4fd5a331473e',
        'eedc5a7d-0320-41a1-b190-79f967b42961'
      ],
    }
  }
}

//Pull out relevant piece of state from redux
const byDays = state.expenditures.byDays;
const byId = state.expenditures.byId;

// convert Id to Object
const idToObjectReducer = (acc,key) => {
    if(byId[key]) {
      acc.push(byId[key]);
    }
    return acc;
};

// Sort Objects by date
const sortByDateComparator = ({createdAt : date1}, {createdAt : date2}) => date1 - date2;

// convert byDays object
const rootReducer = (acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = byDays[key].reduce(idToObjectReducer, []).sort(sortByDateComparator)
  return acc;
};


const result = Object.keys(byDays).reduce(rootReducer, {});


console.log(result);
```

https://repl.it/repls/ShabbyInterestingTrialsoftware

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea. But, it makes sense to start from the `byId` structure so you are working with all the information from the beginning. Because the expenditures in the `byId` object already have `day` information, you can just ignore `byDay` object.

So, start with this structure:

```
const expenditures = {
  byId: {
    '0e1ca91f-aad2-44c7-985a-dfd014bb67fa': {
      id: '0e1ca91f-aad2-44c7-985a-dfd014bb67fa',
      createdAt: 1480510965381,
      description: 'shoes',
      categoryId: 13,
      value: -4,
      day: 1440374400000
    },
    '65711ad0-407d-42ca-aa13-c468a56d6ee6': {
      id: '65711ad0-407d-42ca-aa13-c468a56d6ee6',
      createdAt: 1480510965470,
      description: 'groceries',
      categoryId: 12,
      value: -53.65,
      day: 1440374400000
    },
  }
}
```

And let's assume the first and last days are setup like this:

```
const currentFirstDay = 1440374400000;
const currentLastDay = 1440374400000;
```

Then you can filter and sort `expenditures.byId` and then generate a new object:

```
const filtered = Object.values(expenditures.byId)
  .filter(expenditure => expenditure.day >= currentFirstDay && expenditure.day <= currentLastDay)
  .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);

let byDay = {}
filtered.forEach(expenditure => {
    if (!byDay[expenditure.day]) byDay[expenditure.day] = [];
    byDay[expenditure.day].push(expenditure);
})
```

Which results in this:

```
{
    "1440374400000": [
    {
      categoryId: 13,
      createdAt: 1480510965381,
      day: 1440374400000
      description: 'shoes',
      id: '0e1ca91f-aad2-44c7-985a-dfd014bb67fa',
      value: -4
    },
    {
      categoryId: 12,
      createdAt: 1480510965470,
      day: 1440374400000
      description: 'groceries',
      id: '65711ad0-407d-42ca-aa13-c468a56d6ee6',
      value: -53.65
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Right. However in the result I need expenditures are grouped by day with day as a key.